# Is there a TS configuration parameter I'm missing to force a type from a union?

Tags: node.js, typescript, stripe-payments, nestjs

I have a problem with the Stripe Node.js API (apiVersion '2020-08-27' - which as of 2022-07-21 is current).

The customers.retrieve method returns a response of type `Promise<Stripe.Response<Stripe.Customer | Stripe.DeletedCustomer>>`.

According to the documentation, and a Github thread here: [Use discriminated unions to easier make distinciton between types](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-js/issues/241), if the response from customers.retrieve has property `deleted` = `true`, then the type should be `DeletedCustomer`, and otherwise should be `Customer`.

The link above indicates that it is sufficient to check the deleted property as below, and then TypeScript should be able to discern that the response represents a `Customer` instead of a `DeletedCustomer`.

```
let customer = await this.stripe.customers.retrieve(customerId, { expand: ['subscriptions'] })
if (!customer.deleted) {
  const subscriptions = customer.subscriptions[0]
}
```

However, none of the properties of `Customer` are available within the conditional block as expected.

I have a solution that seems to do what I need - but it doesn't seem "by the book", and I wish that I could figure out if TypeScript can fix this issue for me.  Here is my solution:

```
if (customer.deleted) return
customer = <Stripe.Response<Stripe.Customer>>customer
const subscription = customer.subscriptions[0]
```

Edit to add:
I should add that this is a Nest.js project.

Comment: I'm not sure why it isn't working for you, but you can specify the type directly like this `let customer: Stripe.Customer | Stripe.DeletedCustomer = await this.stripe.customers.retrieve(customerId, { expand: ['subscriptions'] })` and see if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem config option is:
`"strictNullChecks": false`, and the lack of `strict: true` in the tsconfig.

The default of strictNullChecks is true if strict, false otherwise.  https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strictNullChecks

Thus, `"strict": true` must be used to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing this work fine with typescript 4.4.4.

[See codesandbox link here](https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-lumiere-ej8shf?file=/src/index.ts:0-547)

```js
import { Stripe } from "stripe";

const stripe = new Stripe("x", { apiVersion: "2020-08-27" });

const fn = async () => {
  const customer = await stripe.customers.retrieve("x", {
    expand: ["subscriptions"]
  });
  if (!customer.deleted) {
    console.log(customer); // customer here resolves to Stripe.Customer & { ... }
    const subscriptions = customer.subscriptions;
    const subscription = subscriptions && subscriptions.data[0]; // note that this is slightly different from your code
  } else {
    console.log(customer); // customer here resolves to Stripe.DeletedCustomer & { ... }
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm on 4.3.5 - so I can't imagine that's it.  I edited my question to add that this is a Nest.js project - I'm not sure if their configuration is missing something.

Comment: Happy to look into it more if you're able to provide a minimal reproduction on something like codesandbox @MichaelJay

Comment: I've never done that before.  Here is a link - I think I've done it correctly.

It is a tsconfig issue, because when I copied my tsconfig into CodeSandbox, it went from working to not working.  This is a great lead - thank you.
https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-rgb-pr07yp?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: Of note - my else block `customer` also resolve sto Stripe.DeletedCustomer - but it's still not resolving to Stripe.Customer in the if block.

Comment: Got it.  The problem is that "strictNullChecks" has to be removed, and "strict" : true has to be added.  This caused a host of issues.

I am relatively new to TypeScript, and I'm not sure if making this change to the configuration is worth the clean-up that I'll have to do, given my timeline.

Comment: Update:  I went through about 100 errors that resulted from the difference in the tsconfig.  I think this was a very good choice.  Many thanks @g2jose in helping me get to the point where I realized what needed to happen.